# is there a code for delaying a microcontroller

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I am programming a PIC16F84A microcontroller to monitor three doors, if one of the doors is open it should trigger an alarm and write `D1`, `D2` 0R `D3` on a seven segment display. OR it should write ALL if all doors are open or `NONE` if no door is open.

I wrote a program but I am struggling to set a delay of one second between letters when being displayed on a 7 segment display.

I tried to set a delay between `N` and `O` for `NONE` but it just got stuck on N and did not display the rest of those letters

Here is a program:

```
D1 EQU B'100'
D2 EQU B'100'
D3 EQU B'100'


LIST P=PIC16F84A
#INCLUDE<P16F84A.INC>



    BSF STATUS,5
    MOVLW 0X0F
    MOVWF TRISA
    CLRF TRISB
    BCF STATUS,5

  
T1 BTFSS PORTA,0
      GOTO T2
      GOTO T4
T2 BTFSS PORTA,1
      GOTO T3
      GOTO T6
T3 BTFSS PORTA,2
      GOTO S1
      GOTO S2
T4 BTFSS PORTA,1
      GOTO T7
      GOTO T5
T5 BTFSS PORTA,2
      GOTO S7
      GOTO S8
T6 BTFSS PORTA,2
      GOTO S3
      GOTO S4
T7 BTFSS PORTA,2
      GOTO S5
      GOTO S6
S1 MOVLW 0X37
    MOVWF PORTB

ORG 30H 
Delay MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D1
      MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D2
      MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D3

Del1 NOP
      DECFSZ D3,1
      GOTO Del1
      DECFSZ D2,1
      GOTO Del1
      DECFSZ D1,1
      GOTO Del1
      

    MOVLW 0X3F
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X37
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X79
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO T1
    BCF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
    
S2 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X4F
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
S3 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5B
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
S4 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5B
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X4F
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
S5 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X06
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
S6 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X06
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X4F
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH
    
S7 MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X06
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5E
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X5B
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH

S8 MOVLW 0X77
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X38
    MOVWF PORTB
    MOVLW 0X38
    MOVWF PORTB
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    BSF PORTA,4
    GOTO SWITCH

SWITCH BTFSS PORTA,3
       GOTO STOP
       GOTO T1
STOP BCF PORTA,4
      GOTO T1
    END
```

Comment: PIC16F84A has timer. Use it.

Comment: pic instruction timing is also very deterministic so you can do a count loop as well.

Comment: What is the oscillator frequency of PIC?

Answer (score 0):

Well your code flow is really hard to read. You could have structured your code and made it more legible. Anyways.. The `O` character isn't being written following the `N` because the CPU gets stucked in the delay part.
The delay is looping for a large amount of time due to the way you write it. You always branch to the same point after decrementing each value. Since you don't reload the values, it starts over to count
down from 255 again and again, almost infinitely or a considerably large amount of time.

```
Delay MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D1
      MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D2
      MOVLW D'100'
      MOVWF D3

Del1 NOP
      DECFSZ D3,1 ; CPU gets stucked
      GOTO Del1
      DECFSZ D2,1
      GOTO Del1
      DECFSZ D1,1
      GOTO Del1   ; between these lines
```

Assuming that you have calculated the delay values correctly, the correct way of program flow should be like the following:

```
Delay:
  BANKSEL D1
  MOVLW   D'100'
  MOVWF   D1
Reload2
  MOVLW   D'100'
  MOVWF   D2
Reload3
  MOVLW   D'100'
  MOVWF   D3

DelayLoop
  DECFSZ  D3,1 ;
  GOTO    DelayLoop
  DECFSZ  D2,1
  GOTO    Reload3
  DECFSZ  D1,1
  GOTO    Reload2
```

I also noted that your memory allocation looks somewhat weird. You meant to
allocate memory for `D1`, `D2` and `D3` variables I guess. But you actually assign them all to the same memory location which is 4 in decimal. This location corresponds to the FSR register which manages the indirect memory operations.

```
D1 EQU B'100'
D2 EQU B'100'
D3 EQU B'100'
```

You're supposed to use the *General Purpose Registers GPR* to allocate memory for application specific variables. The GPR memory starts from address 0x0C, 12 in decimal. So you need to declare them as following:

```
D1 EQU 0xC
D2 EQU 0xD
D3 EQU 0xE
```